# $.extend is not a function with Toastr and NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules, toastr

I am using NodeJS and trying to implement error messaging with Toastr. I keep getting the error `$.extend is not a function` whenever I try to use it. I am importing toastr into the file with `var toastr = require('toastr')` and have even tried changing a component of the toastr.js file (see https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr/issues/559), which results in another error, `jQuery needs a window in a document`. I understand that the issue must have something to do with jQuery, but am unable to solve it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: jQuery is a DOM library for the browser, not a server-side thing. What exactly are you trying to do here? Why are you running this in node?

Comment: Just add toastr error notifications for the app. The error messages I am getting specifically mention jQuery, but I have no ideas what the problem really is.

Comment: No you don't understand, toastr is for the *browser*, node runs on the *server*. Why are you trying to run something for the *client* on the *server*?

Comment: I agree with you - I probably don't understand :), but the app is a web app and I have used toastr notifications for other similar, projects in the past. All I want is to get an error message when a user skips required fields in forms, the app crashes, etc. Do you have any other recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Toastr (and jQuery) are designed to run in a browser, not in Node.js.

It doesn't make sense to use it with `require` except as part of a toolchain that involves a bundler (such as Webpack or Parcel).

If you want to output an error message from Node.js and display it in a browser then you need some way of communicating between the two programs (e.g. by responding to a request the browser made or sending a message over a websocket). You can have a program running in the browser that uses toastr to display it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you have any recommendations on other packages I could use for error handling/messages?

Comment: @Alex88 — `console.log` is suitable for most cases. Anything else would depend on specific needs.

Comment: Hi Quentin - Thanks for the input, once again. I want something that will alert the user, though, as an actual error message. Any ideas?

Comment: See the last paragraph of the answer.